# Notepad++ like editor for linux which highlights words on right clicking

Tags: linux, text-editor, notepad++

Sorry for the extremely bad title. What I'm looking for is the notepad++ feature where I can highlight words on right clicking and choosing one of the 5 styles (so that all instances of that word get highlighted with that color), in some editor in linux (Red hat). I know this might be a stupid request, but I find that it helps me in understanding new code.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe this belongs to Superuser (superuser.com) instead of stackoverflow. you can use the same login :) good luck on your search.

Comment: @Prozaker: True, or even better: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you tried running Notepad++ under Wine?

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys :)
@Jonathan, I've heard it's really slow under Wine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SciTE can do this. After you install it, create a script named SciTEStartup.lua in your home directory and add the following line in your ~/.SciTEUser.properties file:

```
ext.lua.startup.script=$(SciteUserHome)/SciTEStartup.lua
```

After that you can install [this script](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SciteMarkWord) as described and see all occurrences of a word using Ctrl+. (Ctrl+, to clear).

Answer (score 0):

The default editor Gedit does this with an additional plug-in installed from here: https://github.com/mmuell23/mmuell23